Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service worker: InvalidStateError
When I try to open .png file or any python file that has text in it, I get:
Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service worker: InvalidStateError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state.
A week ago everything worked, as far as I know, I didn't change anything in VSCode. How can I fix this?

Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled command in the command palette)? If not, then do an extension bisect to figure out what extension is causing it.
